# Composite control, multiple instances on page, validation groups set, but inner text breaks validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I can use C# or VB.NET for this problem.

I have a composite control:

```
<me:MyControl />
```

It generates the following:

- Name
- RequiredFieldValidator for Name
- Submit Button

The first problem I ran into was when placing multiple instances on the page. When I did so, all of the instances, well... actually anything that triggered a submit, caused validation on all the instances.

I'm implementing INamingContainer so not really sure why this is happening. It's confusing because I looked at the JavaScript generated on the page and everything did in fact have unique id's.

Regardless, I used the composite control's base instance to solve that:

```
validator.ValidationGroup = "form_" & ClientID
```

Problem solved. Now each instance validated independently.

New problem. I want literal text in my control:

```
<me:MyControl>Hello World</me:MyControl>
```

I added:

```
<ParseChildren(False)>
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits CompositeControl
...
End Class
```

No errors were thrown, but now validation is being triggered on every instance again! I have no idea why. So to be clear, if I have 5 instances of this "mini-form" then asterisks are showing next to every field if I click submit on just one of the instances. This only happens when there's a space or any type of text between the opening and closing tags of my control.

Even a simple space: `<me:MyControl> </me:MyControl>` does the same thing.

Here's a basic version of my control:

```
<ParseChildren(False), PersistChildren(True)>
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits CompositeControl
    Implements INamingContainer

    Public Custom Event Submit As EventHandler

        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            Events.AddHandler(EventSubmitKey, value)
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            Events.RemoveHandler(EventSubmitKey, value)
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            CType(Events(EventSubmitKey), EventHandler).Invoke(sender, e)
        End RaiseEvent

    End Event

    Protected Overridable Sub OnSubmit(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim submitHandler As EventHandler =
                CType(Events(EventSubmitKey), EventHandler)
        If submitHandler IsNot Nothing Then
            submitHandler(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        OnSubmit(EventArgs.Empty)
        
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()


        Controls.Clear()

        
        txtName = New TextBox
        txtName.ID = "txtName"
        txtName.Text = NameText

        Required_Name = New RequiredFieldValidator
        With Required_Name
            .Text = "*"
            .Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic
            .ControlToValidate = txtName.ID
            .ValidationGroup = "Form_" & Me.ClientID
        End With

        
        btnSubmit = New Button
        With _btnSubmit
            .ID = "btnSubmit"
            .Text = "Submit"
            .ValidationGroup = "Form_" & Me.ClientID
        End With

        AddHandler _btnSubmit.Click, AddressOf btnSubmit_Click

        ' Add controls to the tree

        With Controls
            .Add(txtName)
            .Add(Required_Name)

            .Add(btnSubmit)
        End With

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        AddAttributesToRender(writer)
        With writer
            .RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
            txtName.RenderControl(writer)
            Required_Name.RenderControl(writer)
            .RenderEndTag()
            .RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
            btnSubmit.RenderControl(writer)
            .RenderEndTag()

        End With

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RecreateChildControls()
        EnsureChildControls()
    End Sub

End Class
```

### Update

If I override the AddParsedSubObject:

```
Protected Overrides Sub AddParsedSubObject(obj As Object)

End Sub
```

And force the base not to execute, the problem goes away, but so does my literal content. The source of this method adds the control to the collection. I still don't see how this affects validation. Also, if it's a databoundliteralcontrol, as in there are databinding expressions, the values of those expressions aren't available in this sub regardless, so I can't just parse it into a property and move on. I need it later in the life cycle.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.ControlToValidate = _txtName.ClientID` instead of `.ID` as well?

Comment: @Alexander I don't think so but I'll try for the heck of it. .NET is supposed to take care of generated the "ClientID" for the client-side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another set of eyes on this, the issue was resolved by using a GUID as the validation group instead of ClientID.

The reason for this is simple, yet not super obvious:

A `CompositeControl` has a `ClientID`, due to its base. It's just another control.

When there is inner text, that's parsed later, and I'm trying to use ClientID before it's available for the control.

The resolution was to use a GUID as the validation group instead of ClientID, again, because ClientID wasn't available yet in the life cycle due to the inner text.

Very crazy stuff indeed.